# Putty as an interface between cmd and sh

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ssh, cmd

What do I have:

- a local Windows machine and a remove Linux server
- a cmd script and an sh script on the local machine
- a specific restriction to keep no scripts on the remote machine

What do I need:

- the local cmd script to start an SSH client with specified parameters (ip:port, username@password), with that client executing the local sh script on the remote machine and passing the output back to the local machine, to the cmd script's STDOUT

Example:

whatever.cmd:

```
@echo off
client.exe -ip 192.168.1.1 -port 22 -username notroot -password mypwd -exec remote.sh >192.168.1.1_media.txt
```

Alternatively, if I convert the sh script to a set of commands sepated by ; symbol, the example may look like this:

```
@echo off
client.exe -ip 192.168.1.1 -port 22 -username notroot -password mypwd -command 'head `ps -aux`;df -h | grep media' >192.168.1.1_media.txt
```

Is there an SSH client that can be run in this way? If not, how can I make Putty do the job without using GUI?

Comment: There is no way to execute the script without moving it to the server first. You could use sftp (if enabled on the server, but most likely it is if ssh is running anyway) to upload that script, and have the script delete itself after running. SO the only tihng left now is to actually run it.

Comment: Can I pass is as a set of commands divided by ; symbol instead, then (like -command 'head `ps -aux`;df -h | grep media')? And no, sftp is disabled on the server.

Comment: If you can pass a command to run on the server, you should be able to pass multiples, separated by ;, surronded by quotes. Yes.

Comment: How do I do this with Putty without using the GUI?

Comment: Unix ssh has the -t command line option, but I don't think this is available on putty.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `plink` is something for you. It is like `putty` but instead of keyboard and screen as input and output you can use pipes for input and output.

This way you can echo the lines of your script to the server.

Plink is downloadable at the putty site: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

There is also an extensive and detailed manual on that site.

Comment: +1. Specifically, the cmd.exe command would be `type scriptfile.bash | plink -pw password user@host bash -s`. The script file must not contain DOS style eol.